# How to match a particular string rendered on the webpage through mocha and chai

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, chai

I am using mocha and chai packages to build a test suite  in my Node JS application. As of now I am validating a test case as pass/fail by checking the status code (200) returned when a page is successfully rendered.

How can I validate the page as pass/fail based on what I am rendering on the page. For example if the the page displays "Welcome to Express" , I want to match any one of the words "Welcome" or "Express" to validate it as pass.

Below is the snippet of my code to check the status code:

```
describe('Home Page', () => {
    it('This is the Home page', (done)=> {
        chai.request(server)
        .get('/home')
        .end((error, respond) => {            
            expect(respond.statusCode).to.equal(200);                      
        done();
        });
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a simple solution you may directly use the content/string you want to match in the expect() statement as below:

```
describe('Home Page', () => {
    it('This is the Home page', (done)=> {
        chai.request(server)
        .get('/home')
        .end((error, respond) => {            
            expect(/Welcome/, done);                     
        done();
        });
    }); 
});
```

Comment: This is working and exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.